# passing dynamic parameter to stored procedure crystal report

Tags: stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I used to work on sap crystal report with table / view but I do have new task to use procedure which accept dynamic parameter , I tried passing static value it's working but dynamic not working

kindly advice me

I created new parameter and in record selectionformula  I assigned this value to procedure parameter 
{?ProcVal}={?NewVAL}

Answer (score 0):

Create a dynamic parameter in a main report (acting as a container for the real report placed as a subreport within the main report).

Pass the parameter value (or a formula based on the records in the main report) as a subreport link to the subreport. And connect that link to the stored procedure parameter in the subreport.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the parameter {?ProcVal}, change it to "Dynamic" in the List of Values dropdown.
Under "Value", choose the column from the dropdown.